# Display the current location / address / area name on a Marker in google map

Tags: android, google-places-api, android-maps-v2

I created a basic application which displays a google map as well as a marker. The marker appears on the map clearing the previous location wherever I click. Now, I am trying to display the location name / address / area name on the marker wherever I click on the google map. But my application is getting closed unfortunately.I used a toast temporary for confirming the display. The listener I used is this :

Temporary.java file

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                 List<Address> address = null;
                 Geocoder geocode;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                geocode = new Geocoder(Temporary.this,Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    address=geocode.getFromLocation(currentGPS.latitude, currentGPS.longitude, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String address1=address.get(0).getCountryName();
                Toast.makeText(Temporary.this,address1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I tried one more Listener which is as follows :

```
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

            List<Address> address = null;
             Geocoder geocode;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            geocode = new Geocoder(Temporary.this,Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                address=geocode.getFromLocation(point.latitude, point.longitude, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
             markerOptions.position(point);
             markerOptions.title("Area Name :"+address.get(0).getLocality());
             googleMap.clear();
             googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        }
    });
```

Still its not working. Where I am mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

Here i hope this link will help you http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-reverse-geocoding-at-touched-location-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: Thank you for your suggested link. But this solution is just displaying the marker and the map. When tapped on marker, it doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can set up a InfoWindow over your map and customize it on the current selection.

```
        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                        currentInfo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_layout, null);
                        //Do what you want with the view
                        return currentInfo;
                    }
        }
```

Remember the marker has his own location, title, color, etc.